# How can I use CiviRules to update case status based on age of case (set to inactive or similar)

Tags: civicase, civirules, actions, trigger, condition

I want to use Civi Rules to make older cases have their status automatically updated to something appropriate like 'inactive'.

I found https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/basic-example-hints/#daily-trigger-for-case-activity

So I created a rule with Linked Trigger = 'Daily trigger for case activity', and Linked Condition 'Days since Last Case Activity- = 90 days.

However, I wasn't able to create a suitable Linked Action. I selected 'Set the Status of a Case' - seems like the obvious and only suitable option - but this generates the error 'This action is not available with trigger Daily trigger for case activity'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A possible workaround may be to have a custom field and set that (dormant = yes) via the trigger above and then have a second rule to set the status for a field value comparison on the custom field

Answer (score 1):

You probably hit upon a bug in CiviRules. I would assume that case actions should work with this trigger. What you can do report a bug at https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civirules and if you are technical a fix would also be very welcome! Or if you aren't technical enough you can ask a developer/CiviCRM partner to fix this for you (you probably have to pay them for their time).

You can also use the work around mentioned by Rebecca.

Comment: Hi Jaap, thanks for your reply. I will file a bug report, and have been discussing this with our development partners. NB I tried Rebecca's workaround, and some variations, but kept meeting similar problems e.g. error 'This action is not available with trigger Activity is added'. Seems like the action Set the Status of a Case is incompatible with numerous triggers. Will add full details to the bug report.

Comment: Bug report here: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civirules/-/issues/184